# Error modifying primitive prototype with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

A few months ago, I looked up how to extend primitive prototypes in Typescript and found that I needed to create an interface of the type with a method stub. At the time, it worked, though maybe this error was there and I didn't notice.

My code:

```
interface String {
    ucFirst(): string;
}

interface Array<T> {
    sum(): number;
}

String.prototype.ucFirst = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}

Array.prototype.sum = function () {
    return this.reduce(function (sum, value) {
        return sum + value;
    }, 0);
}
```

In VSCode, I don't get any error, but when I compile (this is an Angular project using Angular CLI), in Chrome 60, I get told `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` under `String {`. I can't seem to figure out why it's complaining there and not under Array, nor why this only happens on compilation. Any advice?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t6zqxm10/ It works fine. Which version of typescript do you use?

Comment: Hm... I should have checked in a stand-alone environment. Wonder if it's an Angular issue... I'm currently on 2.3.3.

Comment: The latest VSC comes with TS 2.5.2. Can you update your TS dependency?

Comment: I'll do that and see if it helps; but given it works in a fiddle and not in my package, I'm suspecting it's how Angular is compiling everything.